# How to create a bi-directional and regex?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

**Problem Statement:** I need to create a regex to match text bi-directionally. What I mean by bi-directionally is that I want a regex to match occurence of of few keywords in any order i.e. if I say A bi-directional and B, then it shall work as `A.*B` and `B.*A`. I need a single regex to do so.

To explain by taking example of three strings a, b and c, I need a regex which would match: "randomstring a randomstring b randomstring c", "randomstring a randomstring c randomstring b", "randomstring b randomstring a randomstring c", "randomstring b randomstring c randomstring a", "randomstring c randomstring a randomstring b", "randomstring c randomstring b randomstring a"

**What I have tried:** I came up with following two regexes that will solve the purpose:

1. `(A.*B|B.*A)`
2. `((?=.*A).*(?=.*B).*)`

Now the problem is that if I use second way to create regex which have five keywords I come up with something like `((?=.*a).*(?=.*b).*(?=.*c).*(?=.*d).*(?=.*e).*)`. On larger sentences, I get following exception

> RecursionLimit = '_MatchingRegex._info.RecursionLimit' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   base {System.SystemException} = {"Error in pcre16_fullinfo, code: -33"}.

I am using .NET version of PCRE for processing.

And, if I use first way the regex will become quite long and hard to maintain. It may have performance issues as well, as performance of regex engine depends on length of regex as well.

Right now I am looking for insights on what would be the best approach accoring to you and if there is any other way of implementing this regex. Please note that I have to write a single regex for this and I cannot just search for occurence of the substring in the larger text (use Contains or similar methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To explain by taking example of three strings a, b and c, I need a regex which would match: "abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"

```
^(?=.*?a)(?=.*?b)(?=.*?c)[abc]{3}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oY2sI2/1)

Comment: hi avinash, sorry for the confusion. I have editted the test cases. The change is that anything can occur between a,b and c however the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: then this `^(?=.*?a)(?=.*?b)(?=.*?c).*[abc].*[abc].*[abc].*$`